# Make few values onto a different column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a week level data which i would like make into a column. This is the input
[image]

Here is how i want the output to look like:
[image]

**Sample**:

```
print (df)
     Week  Category   Sales
0  202001    Red      100
1  202001    White    200
2  202002    Red      300
3  202002    White    700
4  201901    Red      800
5  201901    White    900
6  201902    Red      100
7  201902    White    200
```

**Sample**:

output:

```
     Week  Category   2019  2020
0    1     Red        800   100
1    1     White      900   900
2    2     Red        100   300
3    2     White      200   700
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use modulo and integer division for extract `year`s and `week`, create MultiIndex by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and last reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with convert index to column and removing columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index([df['Week'] % 100, df['Week'] // 100])['Sales']
         .unstack()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)

   Week  2019  2020
0     1   700   100
1     2   800   200
2     3   900   300
```

EDIT: You need to add column name in `set_index`:

```
df1 = (df.set_index([df['Week'] % 100, 'Category', df['Week'] // 100])['Sales']
         .unstack()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   Week Category  2019  2020
0     1      Red   800   100
1     1    White   900   200
2     2      Red   100   300
3     2    White   200   700
```

Comment: Thanks for this Jezrael, this works fine, but only if there is only one record for each week. How can i make this work when are there duplicates every week?

Comment: @vevekseetharaman - If there are duplicates do you need `sum` them?

Comment: No, i want them to just shift as columns. Does it make sense? Do you want me to give more details?

Comment: @vevekseetharaman - Yes, please more details.Best change data sample (in text) with expected output. thanks.

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly! thank you so much Jezrael. And apologies for the bad formatting. Will try to make it better.

Comment: @vevekseetharaman - no problem, each answer will be better. Btw, for future question can help [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) ;)